# Cisco QOS vonage phone

Tags: cisco, qos

I have a cisco 3550 switch. I have a vonage router plugged into that switch and also a obitalk router. I want to give both the vonage and obitalk boxes maximum priority. I started reading about QOS but am not sure I've done the right thing. I put both phone boxes in their own Vlans.

Can this be done with just a few config lines ? I don't want to continue if thats not the right thing.

Comment: Is it sufficient to just add "auto qos voip trust" to each of the above mentioned interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Quality of Service is what you want.